# Saving cells with extra decimal places

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, precision, worksheet-function

I am entering `16.19` as the value of one cell, saving it as a Excel 2007 (.xlsx) file, and saving it again as a .xml file.  When I open the .xml file with Sublime editor, the cell shows as `16.190000000000001`.

Does anyone know why this isn't simply saving as `16.19`?

This is also happening for `16.49`, `16.69` and `16.99` (not `16.29`, `16.39`, `16.59`, `16.79` or `16.89`).

Answer (score 1):

Lots of places describe why, [for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel). To remove the surplus when in Excel convert by using =ROUND({cellref},2) or convert to string and, if necessary, use =LEFT({cellref},5).

Comment: Hey pnuts, Thanks for your answer.  I could create another hidden column that would strip off the excess decimal places using the techniques you mentioned above, but do you know if there is a way to limit the decimal places for the column that contains the actual values? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  I think I found the issue we are seeing.  When you enter 16.19 into the cell, it works just fine and I don't have extra decimal places.  But when I copy and paste a value that appears to be 16.19 (it's displaying 16.19 in the cell and the formula bar), our system is processing the value as 16.188888888889.  I think there's something wrong with is ACTUALLY in the copied cell.

Comment: Haha, yes, quite frustrating. I have typed 16.19 into Excel and it works fine, but there is a copied value that appears to be 16.19 in the cell and in the formula bar, but our system is evaluating it as 16.188888889. I'm researching now to perform validation when a value is pasted into a cell (since validation doesn't work on pasted values, only if you type it in).